# When I load my web page I get: "The page says There was a problem: 0 error"

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to take a JSON file with a list of projects and list them in my HTML file. I find it hard to find any information from the error message and I am pretty new to Javascript so do not really know how to debug. I have seen other similar examples and I pretty much follow the same structure. I have linked the javascript code below but the git hub repo is: https://github.com/toccht/toccht.github.io

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
    url: "json/projects.json",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(responseData, status){
      output = "<ul>";
      $.each(responseData.menuItem, function(i, menuItem) {
       output += '<li>' + menuItem.menuName + '</li>';
       //output += '<li>' + menuItem.menuDesc + '</li>';
      });

      output += "</ul>";
      $('#projectsOutput').html(output);

   }, error: function(msg) {
    // there was a problem
   alert("There was a problem: " + msg.status + " " + msg.statusText);
  }

 });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/projects.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>

   <div id="websiteHeader">

      <h1>Trevor Tocchet</h1>
      
      <div id="navBar">

        <a href = "index.html"> Home </a>
        <a href = "https://www.trevortphoto.com">Portfolio</a>
        <a href = "projects.html"> Projects </a>
        <a href = "trevor-tocchet-resume.pdf"> Resume </a>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pageContent">
     <h1>Projects</h1>
     <p>Content</p>

     <div id="projectsOutput"></div>
     
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This response implies the error is happening on the server side - during the ajax request to json/projects.json.  You should be able to debug in your browser to see what is being returned by the server (if anything).  You might also make sure the end point (json/projects.json) is valid.

Comment: As a side note, as of jQuery 3.0 the "success" and "error" callbacks have been depreciated.  You might consider refactoring your code to use the done(), fail(), always() methods instead:  More information can be found here  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with how I have my folder structure in my repo? Could that be messing it up?

Comment: It looks fine to me, but I would test in your browser to see if the "projects,json" file is even being returned by the server.  For example, if the web address is: http://www.example.com/index.html then type the url http://www.example.com/json/projects.json in the browser bar to see if it loads the json file in the browser window.

Comment: Yes, I just tried that and when I type it in, it shows the json file text.

Comment: You might have a different problem all together though...  Are you "running" this website directly from your file system on your local machine?  In other words, in the browser bar does the website start with "http://" or does it start with "c:/" or "file://"?  If it's the later, it won't work because JS will be blocked from loading files via ajax() directly from the file system (in most cases).  In order for the code to work (or at least to test effectively), you should upload the files to your server or make sure you have a local web server running to serve up the website files.

Comment: I am basically running it locally for aesthetic purposes (HTML/CSS) then commit and push my changes to the github repo which uses github pages to host the website. I think I recall looking up that javascript should work with github pages.

Comment: It can run on github - but the code will not work on your local machine (if you don't have a web server running).  So best way to test is to push the files to github and test.  I did notice the projects.js file on ithub doesn't have the correct link: url: "projects.json" should be changed to "json/projects.json"

Comment: This is why https://toccht.github.io/projects.html is getting a "404" error - meaning the ajax path is not correct and the file is not found.

Comment: Why would the path not be found? Sorry if that's a dumb queestion.

Comment: I saw you made that change, now the code works on github.  Are you seeing that?

Comment: Yes, I just got that now. I honestly have no idea what the change was lmao

Comment: Telling the server exactly where a file is is required.  So in your javascript file you were telling github to search for the projects.json file at https://toccht.github.io/projects.json instead of https://toccht.github.io/json/projects.json  Because of this, github was returning a 404 error (file not found).

Comment: Looks like you are good to go.  If you could up-vote one of my responses that would be appreciated.  Good luck!

Comment: Ah I see, I had that change on my local machine and because I did not push it I could not actually test the javascript. Thank you!